# Regular expression extraction in text editors

Tags: regex, user-interface, editor

I'm kind of new to programming, so forgive me if this is terribly obvious (which would be welcome news).

I do a fair amount of PHP development in my free time using pregmatch and writing most of my expressions using the free (open source?) Regex Tester.

However frequently I find myself wanting to simply quickly extract something and the only way I know to do it is to write my expression and then script it, which is probably laughable, but welcome to my reality. :-)

What I'd like is something like a simple text editor that I can feed my expression to (given a file or a buffer full of pasted text) and have it parse the expression and return a document with only the results.

What I find is usually regex search/replace functions, as in Notepad++ I can easily find (and replace) all instances using an expression, but I simply don't know how to only extract it...

And it's probably terribly obvious, can expression match only the inverse? Then I could use something like (just the expression I'm currently working on):

```
<a href="/browse/0/b/-dbm/a/0-0/1200000([^/]*)/0.html">([^<]*)</a>
```

And replace everything that *doesn't* match with nothing. But I'm sure this is something common and simple, I'd really appreciate any poniters.

FWIW I know grep and I *could* do it using that, but I'm hoping their are better gui'ified solution I'm simply ignorant of.

Thanks.

Zach

---

What I was hoping for would be something that worked in a more standard set of gui tools (ie, the tools I might already be using). I appreciate all the responses, but using perl or vi or grep is what I was hoping to avoid, otherwise I would have just scripted it myself (of course I did) since their all relatively powerful, low-level tools.

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. As a senior systems administrator the cli tools are familiar to me, I'm quite fond of them. Working at home however I find most of my time is spent in a gui, like Netbeans or Notepad++. I just figure there would be a simple way to achieve the regex based data extraction using those tools (since in these cases I'd already be using them).

Something vaguely like what I was referring to would be [this](http://www.lfmseek.com/rss/extractor.php) which will take aa expression on the first line and a url on the second line and then extract (return) the data.

It's ugly (I'll take it down after tonight since it's probably riddled with problems).

Anyway, thanks for your responses. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, we all gotta start somewhere right?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a text editor with good regex support, I highly recommend Vim.  Vim's regex engine is [quite powerful](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/pattern.html) and is well-integrated into the editor.  e.g.

```
:g!/regex/d
```

This says to delete every line in your buffer which doesn't match pattern `regex`.

```
:g/regex/s/another_regex/replacement/g
```

This says on every line that matches `regex`, do another search/replace to replace text matching `another_regex` with `replacement`.

If you want to use commandline `grep` or a Perl/Ruby/Python/PHP one-liner any other tool, you can filter the current buffer's text through that tool and update the buffer to reflect the results:

```
:%!grep regex
:%!perl -nle 'print if /regex/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried nregex.com ?

http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx

There's a plugin for Netbeans here, but development looks stalled:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/Regex

http://wiki.netbeans.org/RegularExpressionsModuleProposal

You might also try The Regulator:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/

Answer (score 0):

Most regex engines will allow you to match the opposite of the regex.

Usually with the ! operator.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), and [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) if you're stuck on a Windows box.

```
echo "text" | grep <a href="/browse/0/b/-dbm/a/0-0/1200000([^/]*)/0.html">([^<]*)</a>
```

OR

```
cat filename | grep <a href="/browse/0/b/-dbm/a/0-0/1200000([^/]*)/0.html">([^<]*)</a>
```

Comment: I'm spending most of my time working in a gui editor right now so it's mostly a work-flow thing. I use grep frequently, but mostly at work where I do systems work and spend most of my time in ssh sessions, there vi/grep/awk/sed are perfect, I just thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: I don't think you need "cat filename | " in the second example.  Doesn't grep also work like "grep expression filename"?

Answer (score 0):

I know grep has been mentioned, and you don't want a cli tool, but I think [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) deserves to be mentioned.

> ack is a tool like grep, aimed at
>   programmers with large trees of
>   heterogeneous source code.
>
> ack is written purely in Perl, and
>   takes advantage of the power of Perl's
>   regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A good text editor can be used to perform the actions you are describing.  I use EditPadPro for search and replace functionality and it has some other nice feaures including code coloring for most major formats. The search panel functionality includes a regular expression mode that allows you to input a regex then search for the first instance which identifies if your expression matches the appropriate information then gives you the option to replace either iteratively or all instances.

http://www.editpadpro.com

Answer (score -1):

> What I'd like is something like a
>   simple text editor that I can feed my
>   expression to (given a file or a
>   buffer full of pasted text) and have
>   it parse the expression and return a
>   document with only the results.

You have just described grep. This is exactly what grep does. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing at all (as I mention above, I use it regularly, probably daily).